# WebDriver - Scroll Inside a Div

Tags: java, webdriver

I have a div, under which there is a ul with roughtly 16 li tags inside it. This div is very small, meaning only 4 li tags are visible, and you need to scroll for the rest.

Each li tag has got a link with a specific text.

My requirement is, based on my test case, I need to be able to click a specific link inside this div. Things work fine if the link is in the visible part of the link. But if I have to scroll to find it, it doesn't work.

I tried a couple of things:

Action Builder to send keys Keys.KEY_DOWN - This did not work.

```
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
builder.keyDown(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).perform();
```

This did not work. It gave an error which said

```
key down / Up events only make sense for modifier keys.
```

I also tried the following

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[1];",driver.findElement(By.id("<div-id>")), 100);
```

Both of the above did not work.

Can any one suggest a way of scrolling inside a div until I find an element that I'm supposed to work with?

Thank you,
Sriram

Answer (score 0):

Python code sample of my approach (js part - is what you need). Nice animated scroll. The only thing is to select `inside_element` right

```
def scroll_to_element(driver, element, inside_element=None):
    if not inside_element:
        script = """
            var elem = arguments[0];
            jQuery('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: jQuery(elem).offset().top
                }, 'slow', null
            );
                """
    else:
        script = """
            var elem = arguments[0];
            var inside = arguments[1];
            var posArray = jQuery(arguments[0]).position();
            jQuery(inside).animate({scrollTop: posArray.top}, 'slow', null);
                 """
    driver.execute_script(script, element, inside_element)
```